# Error missing systemd on AWS server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, systemd

I cant seem to figure out how to install systemd. I am attempting to upgrade mysql server on AWS from 5.5 to 5.6. I am getting the following error when trying to install- "Requires: systemd"

Any ideas on what the problem could be or how to get this installed, Ive tried `sudo yum install systemd`.

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
4 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.21-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.21-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.21-2.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.21-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to install packages for RHEL/CentOS, which are not guaranteed to be compatible with Amazon Linux, and very often are not compatible. Amazon Linux is _not_ a clone of these distributions; it was forked from CentOS 5 and has diverged significantly over the last few years.

Comment: On AWS you are better off using MySQL RDS instead of hosting MySQL on EC2. RDS takes care of high availability, patching, backups, etc. All done for you. Always use RDS unless you've got a very good reason why not to.